# when i add product in magento 2 from iphone the image change to landscape

Tags: magento2, product, iphone

I am using codazon theme for Magento 2 and I am facing issue when I open Magento 2 admin from iPhone and start adding images for product all of sudden the images change to landscape, all other places working fine from laptop browser, android, everything working fine but when adding from iPhone the image change to landscape. need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you edit photo in IPhone before upload, it will solve you problem or use below code to rotate all IPhone JPEG images (direct from camera or default) to fix it.

go to `vendor\magento\framework\File\Uploader.php` on line 228, inside try block
add

```
if ((strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPhone') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad')) && exif_imagetype($this->_file['tmp_name']) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
            $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->_file['tmp_name']);
            $rotate = imagerotate($source, 270, 0);
            imagejpeg($rotate, $this->_file['tmp_name']);
        }
```

before  `$this->_result = $this->_moveFile($this->_file['tmp_name'], $destinationFile);` line

this is not a proper solution, but it might solve your problem.

Comment: Awesome Than you so much @Ibrar its really help me, the bug is fixed :) Thank you so much once again.